# unable to view branch pushed to github

Tags: git, github

I cloned a remote read-only repository locally, and then created a new private repo in github and pushed the code into it. I have set the remote read only repo as the origin and also the newly created repo. So now my setup (git remote -v) looks like below:

```
github  git@github.com:sww/AS.git (fetch)
github  git@github.com:sww/AS.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/ABCD/as.git (fetch) [read only repo]
origin  https://github.com/ABCD/as.git (push)
```

Locally, I created another branch from my master, made some changes to it and committed them. Then I pushed this branch to github using the below command:
git push github sribr0131

Now when i check in github in my repo, in the branches dropdown, it says 2 (meaning master and my branch) but when I try to select my branch (sribr0131) it says 404-Page not found.

What am I missing? I am working on ubuntu (12.04)

Answer (score 0):

I can view the branch in my repo now...strange!...guess it updates only after sometime...cheers

Comment: Also you have to logout of github and login again to see the changes you have pushed to you repo...